# Negative numbers need to display with paranthnes

Tags: jsp, el

I have bal = -1000.00 i want to display as (1000.00) in jsp.

```
<c:when test="${((bal) < 0)}">
<(${-1*bal})/>
</c:when>
```

output id (1000)

decimals are discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

`<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" minFractionDigits="2" value="${bal}" />`

will get you '(1000.00)' when bal is -1000.00